Reuse property value
Headings in my org file have a property 'TITLE' and another 'REFERENCE'.
There is also a heading that provides 'Additional Texts'.
There is a heading * Output section.
The 'Output section' will be initially blank. And will then be populated depending on where the cursor is when a particular function executes.
Please see the MWE below. Hope it makes things clear.
Can this be done? How?
#+title: Test
** My heading
:PROPERTIES:
:TITLE:    Title for my heading
:REFERENCE: Ref1 Ref2
:END:

** Another heading
:PROPERTIES:
:TITLE:    Title for another heading
:REFERENCE: Ref3 Ref4
:END:

* Additional Texts
** Additional Text - Option 1
** Additional Text - Option 2

* Output section

When I am on '* My heading', and press some key sequence or execute some function, the following is generated:

Title for my heading (This is coming from the TITLE property of 'My heading')

Additional Text - Option 1

#Ref1 #Ref2 (This is coming from REFERENCE property of 'My heading' with a # added before each word)

Title for my heading (This is coming from the TITLE property of 'My heading')

Additional Text - Option 2

#Ref1 #Ref2 (This is coming from REFERENCE property of 'My heading' with a # added before each word)



When I am on '* Another heading', and press some key sequence or execute some function, the following is generated:

Title for another heading (This is coming from the TITLE property of 'Another heading')

Additional Text - Option 1

#Ref3 #Ref4 (This is coming from REFERENCE property of 'Another heading' with a # added before each word)


Title for another heading (This is coming from the TITLE property of 'Another heading')

Additional Text - Option 2

#Ref3 #Ref4 (This is coming from REFERENCE property of 'Another heading' with a # added before each word)

------


Where does the additional text come from? How do you want to specify the location of the insertion? Given your stated requirements (being able to insert anywhere in this or another buffer), the best I can come up with is to construct the string (which is possible modulo the additional text question) and add it to the kill ring, so you can yank it with C-y wherever tyou want.

@NickD Thanks.
The 'Additional text - Option 1' and 'Additional text - Option 2' can both be in the same file under a different heading, say, '* Additional Text'
The final outcome can go in the same file under some other heading, say, '* Output'

I still don't undestand. Are they property values? What's the connection between My heading and the additional text? Would the Anotrher heading output have the same values for the additional text? Can you expand your example to include a before-and-after view of everything relevant?

@NickD Thanks and apologies for the delayed response. I have substantially modified the question. And it, now, I hope, answers the questions. Please let me know if you need more information.

With the added information, it is now possible to formulate an answer. This answer is formatted as an Org mode file which you can copy locally and test that the answer indeed works.
But there is one caveat: in order to find the Additional texts headline and the Output headline, I am making use of Org ID properties, which allow one to easily find a headline in the current file or a different file. These ID properties are created by visiting the file where the headline is to reside, moving point to that headine, and doing M-x org-id-get-create. This function will add an ID property to the headline and also record the path of the file containing that headline in Org mode'sID database. You can then get back to that location using (org-id-goto "<value of ID>"). although for programs, it's better to use org-id-find to get a marker and then use the marker to get to the appropriate place - that's what I do below.
The caveat is that the values that I show are good for me, but they are not going to be good for you: I ran org-id-get-create on the two headlines, which created the entries in my database, but you will need to run it on your system to create them in your database. So before you do anything else, you should delete the ID properties under Additional Texts and under Output below and recreate as described above.
With that, let's get to the Org mode file. It is basically your example with a Code section added to contain all the code (plus comments and additional helpful (?) remarks)  and your Output section heading elided1:
#+title: Test

* Example

** My heading
:PROPERTIES:
:TITLE:    Title for my heading
:REFERENCE: Ref1 Ref2
:END:

** Another heading
:PROPERTIES:
:TITLE:    Title for another heading
:REFERENCE: Ref3 Ref4
:END:


* Additional Texts
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       a8b5c005-a83c-4b1f-acf4-1ad192404429
:END:
** Additional Text - Option 1
** Additional Text - Option 2
** Additional Text - Option 3


* Output section

...elided...

* Code                                                                      :noexport:

First, you should delete the ID properties under the =Additional
Texts= and =Output= headlines above and create new ones: go to each
headline and do `M-x org-id-get-create`. That will ensure that your
database contains the appropriate entries. Then cut and paste the
values to the two `setq` form below:

#+name: generated-ids
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  ;;; IDs for the "Additional Texts" and "Output" headlines - you should replace the
  ;;; values shown with your own values as described above.
  (defvar my/Additional-Texts-headline-ID)
  (defvar my/Output-headline-ID)

  ;;; Change the values here to whatever values have been generated by `org-id-get-create'
  ;;; locally. If you ever move the files or move the headings to different files, go through
  ;;; the whole initialization again: generate new IDs at the new places, cut-and-paste them below
  ;;; and re-evaluate the  two `setq' forms with `C-c C-e` after each of the closing parens.

  (setq my/Additional-Texts-headline-ID "a8b5c005-a83c-4b1f-acf4-1ad192404429")
  (setq my/Output-headline-ID "7411943a-2a43-4a4d-b6e1-6c1fa375e55f")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: generated-ids
:results:
7411943a-2a43-4a4d-b6e1-6c1fa375e55f
:end:

#+name: utility-functions
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer

    ;;; Function to generate the info for the node with a single additional text entry.
    (defun my/org-node-info (additional)
      "Given some additional text as argument, generate a string consisting of the value
      of the TITLE property, the additional text and the munged value of the REFERENCE property
      as a string."
      (save-excursion
        (org-back-to-heading)
        (concat (org-entry-get nil "TITLE") "\n"
                (when additional (concat additional "\n"))
                (mapconcat (lambda (x) (format "#%s" x)) (split-string (org-entry-get nil "REFERENCE" " ")) " ") "\n"))) 

    ;;; Two functions that help with generating the list of additional texts
    (defun my/org-find-additional-text-headline ()
      "Go to the \"Additional Texts\" heading. Prerequisite: an ID property has
      been created under that heading (using `org-id-get-create') and the
      value of the ID property was cut-and-pasted above."

      (org-id-find my/Additional-Texts-headline-ID 'marker))

    (defun my/org-additional-text-list ()
      "Go to the \"Additional Texts\" headline and return a list of the level=2 headlines under it."

      (save-excursion
        (let ((m (my/org-find-additional-text-headline)))
          (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer m)
            (goto-char m)
            (org-map-entries (lambda () (org-get-heading t t t t)) "LEVEL=2" 'tree)))))

    ;;; Main interface: call `my/org-node-info' repeatedly with each additional text entry as argument
    ;;; and concatenate the results.
    (defun my/org-node-info-with-additional-text ()
      "Generate the desired text and return it."
      (let ((additional-texts (my/org-additional-text-list)))
        (mapconcat (lambda (add) (my/org-node-info add)) additional-texts "\n")))

#+end_src

#+RESULTS: utility-functions
:results:
my/org-node-info-with-additional-text
:end:

Do =C-c C-c= on the =utility-functions= code block above to define all
the functions.

You can test this much by placing your cursor on one of your headlines
and then doing =M-: (my/org-mode-info-with-addition-text)= or doing
=C-c C-c= on the =utility-functions-test= code block that follows (that
only tests the "My heading" case):

#+name: utility-functions-test
#+begin_src elisp :results-drawer
  (save-excursion
     (goto-char 27)   ;; the position of the "My heading" headline
     (my/org-node-info-with-additional-text))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: utility-functions-test
#+begin_example
Title for my heading
Additional Text - Option 1
#Ref1 #Ref2

Title for my heading
Additional Text - Option 2
#Ref1 #Ref2

Title for my heading
Additional Text - Option 3
#Ref1 #Ref2
#+end_example


Writing the output under the =Output= heading is now more-or-less
routine. I've split it into two functions for clarity: the first
function, =my/insert-string-in-output= takes an arbitrary string as
argument and inserts it in the right place. To find the right place, I
take advantage, once again, of =org-id-find= to get to the correct
headline (even in another file) and then I parse the element to find
where the end of the contents of that entry is. That's where the argument
is inserted.

The second function gets the desired output string by calling
=my/org-node-info-with additional text= as illustrated above and then
passes it to =my/insert-string-in-output=. This function is also
marked =interactive= so you can bind it to a key if you want.

#+name: output-headline-functions
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun my/insert-string-in-output (s)
     (save-excursion
       (let ((m (org-id-find my/Output-headline-ID 'marker)))
         (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer m)
           (goto-char m)
           (let* ((entry (org-element-at-point))
                  (end (org-element-property :contents-end entry)))
             (goto-char end)
             (insert "\n\n" s)))))))

  (defun my/insert-org-node-info-in-output ()
    (interactive)
    (my/insert-string-in-output (my/org-node-info-with-additional-text)))

#+end_src

#+RESULTS: output-headline-functions
:results:
my/insert-string-in-output
:end:

Then move =point= to =My heading= and say =M-x my/insert-string-in-output=. Similarly for =Another heading=.

You can bind =my/insert-org-node-info-in-output= to a key (e.g =C-c z=) in the usual way:

#+name: key-binding
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c z") #'my/insert-org-node-info-in-output)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: key-binding
:results:
my/insert-org-node-info-in-output
:end:



You will find the alternative implementation I suggested in my first comment (save the string into the kill-ring) in a footnote2.
EDIT: Minor variations on this theme can be easily accomodated. E.g. the OP's request to get the whole entry as additional text is easily done. The additional text is obtained in my/org-additional-text-list which maps a function on each headline, returning a list of the results. Currently that function calls only org-get-heading so only a list of headings is returned, but the function can do anything it wants, e.g. call org-get-heading and org-get-entry and return the concatenation of the two strings (perhaps with a newline or two to separate them):

(org-map-entries (lambda () (concat (org-get-heading t t t t) 
                                  "\n\n"
                                  (org-get-entry))) "LEVEL=2" 'tree)


Footnotes:
[1] I'm using a separate section called just Output for the output and just to demonstrate the generality of this approach, I've moved it to a separate file:

* Some junk

Junk before the output heading.

* Output
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       7411943a-2a43-4a4d-b6e1-6c1fa375e55f
:END:

* Some more junk

Junk after the output heading.


You could similarly move the Additional Texts headline to another file (but any such movement requires the regeneration of the corresponding ID and the adjustment and re-evaluation of the setq form(s)).
[2] IMO, output functions like the above are too specialized to be
generally useful. I generally prefer the method I suggested in my
initial comment: save the string in the kill ring. Then you can yank
it (perhaps multiple times) wherever you want. If that appeals, here's
an implementation:
#+name: save-into-kill-ring
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun my/insert-org-mode-info-into-kill-ring ()
    (interactive)
    (kill-new (my/org-node-info-with-additional-text)))

#+end_src

#+RESULTS: save-into-kill-ring
:results:
my/insert-org-mode-info-into-kill-ring
:end:

Bind that to C-c z and do C-c z, then switch to your output buffer
and yank with C-y. If you arrange the two buffers in a two-window
configuration, it becomes C-c z C-x o C-y C-x o: seven keystrokes instead
of one, but the destination buffer can be anything and you don't have to do any setup for it.

Thanks a ton. This works perfectly. I can now go to a heading, execute either my/insert-org-mode-info-in-output or my/insert-org-mode-info-into-kill-ring and it does what is expected.

This uses only the level 2 heading under 'Additional Texts'. Will it be possible to use the level 2 heading and the text below it? I could get the text using org-get-entry in place of org-get-heading. But could not get the heading and text both.

You can always call both functions and concatenate the results: just change the (lambda () (org-get-heading ...)) in the org-map-entries call in my/org-additional-text-list to (lambda () (concat (org-get-heading ...) "\n" (org-get-entry))).

But if you have additional questions, you should ask a new question. Questions in comments get lost, because comments cannot be searched (and occasionally comments disappear without trace).

Edited the answer to add the contents of my comment, just so it wouldn't get lost.
